# Google Sheets IMPORTXML for Images

Tags: xml, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I've been using `IMPORTXML` in Google Sheets to automate content generation, as well as some re-posting of stuff. Normally, the stuff I target and have been leveraging this for has had no issue extracting content from a blog post or a share.

Recently, a post came out where I kept getting the **error "#N/A" in the cell,** with the description being "**Error** Imported Xml content can not be parsed."

*I've been using the IMPORTXML as follows:*

`=IMPORTXML(A2,B2)`

A2: `https://www.ibm.com/blog/machine-learning-types/`

B2: `/html/body/div[4]/div/div[1]/amp-img`

I feel this has to be a very simple solution, and I just keep missing it. Help would be appreciated as I'm not a coder by any stretch, but I want to learn! :)

*Below are the steps I've tried to take to mitigate the issue to no avail.*

#### Mitigation Attempt 1

I've found a reference that I should be using `@src` at the end of B2. It should give me the URL, but I'm still not getting it to work.

Alternative B2: `/html/body/div[4]/div/div[1]/amp-img@src` - This doesn't work

---

#### Mitigation Attempt 2

I thought maybe the block I was trying to grab from had some type of issue, so I tried the block below for the article, but this also did not work.

Alternative B2: `/html/body/div[4]/div/div[1]/amp-img/img` - did not work

Alternative B2: `/html/body/div[4]/div/div[1]/amp-img/img@src` - did not work

---

#### Mitigation Attempt 3

Lastly, I tried using the forward slash instead of the @ to identify the parameter I'm looking to grab, which also did not work. :(

Alternative B2: `/html/body/div[4]/div/div[1]/amp-img/img/src` - did not work

Alternative B2: `/html/body/div[4]/div/div[1]/amp-img/src` - did not work

Comment: You are scrapping a webpage using the XPATH.  Best way of solving is to use a browser and let the browser give you the XPATH.  First go to webpage.   The press the three dots in upper left corner of screen and select : More Tools : Developer Tools.  Select Elements.  Then press blue square with arrow.  You can then point with mouse on the webpage and the HTML will be highlighted for the selection.  Then right click the highlighted HTML text and right click and select : Copy : Copy XPATH

Comment: Thanks, @jdweng, that's method was how I was able to get the values in B2 that I was supplying to the IMPORTXML. But I still don't get the image down from the site.

Comment: There is probably JAVA Scripts executing.  See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65647284/importxml-javascript-imported-content-is-empty